# Short story about the last man on a colony planet who dies and is resurrected by aliens, then upgrades himself to understand physics

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'm looking for a short sci-fi story. The last man alive on a colony planet eventually dies outside in the vacuum. Many years later, aliens made of crystal find him and are able to bring back to life.

The man then decides that he wants to understand physics, so he learns what he can then reaches a limit of understanding. He then has to upgrade himself, using the crystal tech of the aliens, to understand the next level. This continues until he needs massive amounts of power to reach the final levels of understanding, so he transforms into a black hole (I think?) and, before it evaporates, sends a single message like 'I get it,' or something of that nature.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Thanks. I have very little other information on it, but must have been 5 years ago I read it. It would have been in an anthology I think, I certainly can't find it online now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like "Understanding Space and Time" by Alastair Reynolds (2005).

A plague wipes out all people on Earth and the last surviving person is John Renfrew, who is in a base on Mars. After he dies in a rover accident, he wakes up back in the Mars base and finds he has been resurrected by crystalline aliens who end up helping him in his quest to understand physics completely by "upgrading" him.

(Also features a holographic Elton John...)

> In space he grew prolifically for fifteen million years. Hot blue
> stars formed, lived and died while he gnawed away at the edges of
> certain intractables. Human civilisations buzzed around him like
> flies. Among them, he knew, were individuals who were engaged in
> something like the same quest for understanding. He wished them well,
> but he had a head start none of them had a hope of ever overtaking.
> Over the years his density had increased, until he was now composed
> mostly of solid nuclear matter. Then he had evolved to substrates of
> pure quark matter. By then, his own gravity had become immense, and
> the Kind reinfoced him with the mighty spars of exotic matter,
> pilfered from the disused wormhole transit system of some
> long-vanished culture. A binary pulsar was harnessed to power him;
> titanic clockwork enslaved for the purposes of pure mentation.

The story can be found in Reynolds' collection "Zima Blue".

Comment: That's the one, thankyou so much!

Comment: FYI, random thought: many of Alastair's stories have been adapted into Netflix's Love Death + Robots anthology series. Not this one in particular, but they did adapt Zima Blue, Beyond the Aquila Rift and others (and the adaptations are pretty good, too!).